# Dilations of a plane that map two circles

Tags: circles, plane-geometry

Given two circles C1 and C2 in a fixed plane P. Find all the dilatations of P that map C1 to C2.

The absolute value of the ratio R'/R=SO'/SO. S is the center point of the line OO' centers of the sphere.

What does it mean when it says ALL the dilations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would solve this byvsetting the dilation point by setting it to the intersection of the tangents. If you think about it, there are two possible places to dilate: one in between the circles, one behind $C_2$.

[image]

I found this image off of the internet (I would draw my own but I'm too lazy :P)

The intersection point of inner tangent lines and the intersection points of the outer tangent lines would be a point where you could scale the circle to match the other. Make sense now?

Comment: Added image :D.